# Tooltip location in nvd3 multiBarHorizontalChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there a way to change tooltip location in multiBarHorizontalChart in nvd3.js library? It shows always on the left side of current bar, but I would like to localize it when mouse pointer is.

Comment: You can change the CSS, see https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/372

Comment: @LarsKotthoff But I cannot set position to current mouse position using CSS

Comment: Right, for that you would have to select the element in D3 and update its position when the cursor position changes.

Comment: Hi Lars Kotthoff, Can you please elaborate how can i update position of tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `gravity` option:

> Description:
>   Can be 'n','s','e','w'. Determines how tooltip is positioned.
>   Input Type(s):
>   string
>   Default:
>   w
>   Example(s):
>   chart.tooltip.gravity("n")

That's how I was able to get mine to work. Docs [here](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip).

Comment: Really helfull. Thanks